# Word for: "A situation that feels like nature is deliberately doing something only because this is the last thing you want to happen"

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if it's sunny for the first time in a week, and you decide to seize the opportunity and go out, it suddenly turns cloudy and rains the moment you step out of your house. Or if you take good care of your looks and preen in front of the mirror for an hour every single time before getting out although you never bump into anyone you know around your neighbourhood, but on the day you are in a rush, and going out looking messy and horrible, you bump into everybody you know, especially those whom you would like to impress.

Is there a word in English to refer to such situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sod's Law!

It is hard to define but is well explained [here](https://www.michael-scannell.com/jottings/journ2.html) by means of examples.

Thomas Hardy novels and the sinking of the Titanic are good illustrations of its mysterious workings.

It is not the same as Murphy's Law.

Comment: Or Finagle's law?

Comment: Finagle's certainly seems closer to Sod's Law than Murphy's does. Is it always mentioned gloomily though? And would it work in all the examples on that page I linked to? And has it stood the test of time?

Comment: I think Sod's Law is more relevant here.